# How to connect vaadin 7 with Google map

Tags: java, google-maps, vaadin

I used com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.GoogleMap component to connect with Google map from vaadin.

I tried the below code.(Vaadin 7.0.2)

```
public class StoresMainView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        setSizeFull();


        GoogleMap googleMap = new GoogleMap(new LatLon(-27.47101, 153.02429), 10.0, "");
        googleMap.setSizeFull();
        googleMap.setImmediate(true);
        googleMap.setMinZoom(4.0);
        addComponent(googleMap);


    }
```

But it gives the below error when running.I added the dependency in my pom.

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation for com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.GoogleMap. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions.
```

In my web.xml I have define the Widget set as below

```
 <init-param>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>com.client.DashboardWidgetSet</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

And my DashboardWidgetSet as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />

    <inherits name="org.vaadin.cssinject.Cssinject_addonWidgetset" />
    <!--  -->

    <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled"
        value="true" />

    <!-- Uncomment the following to compile the widgetset for one browser only. 
        This can reduce the GWT compilation time significantly when debugging. The 
        line should be commented out before deployment to production environments. 
        Multiple browsers can be specified for GWT 1.7 as a comma separated list. 
        The supported user agents at the moment of writing were: ie6,ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera 
        The value gecko1_8 is used for Firefox 3 and later and safari is used for 
        webkit based browsers including Google Chrome. -->
    <!-- <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/> -->

    <!-- WidgetSetOptimizer -->

    <inherits name="org.vaadin.easyuploads.Widgetset" />

    <inherits name="com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.WidgetSet" />

</module>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you recompile the widgetset after adding the add-on dependency to your pom?

Comment: yes I did recompile it

Comment: Can you create a test project isolating the problem? Maybe in github?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the widgetset init-param in your web.xml points to the right widgetset. The default one does not contain any information about the Google Map component's widgets.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I added my init-param  in my post.

Comment: Can't spot anything weird immediately at least. No errors on widgetset compilation? Try adding -pretty to the widgetset compiler parameters to make sure it does not skip any possible errors.